# Matplotlib improve broken axis in subplots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to create a break between subplots but would like to have the left side cover 80% of the plot and the right side 20% of the plot. I adjusted the x-axis as well to cover only the data but ideally, the plot would cover a portion of the same scale so that the data has the same stretch.

Also, is there a way to have the 2 sublplots closer to each other with a breakline in between?
The .csv file with the data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LvKs3T2cMxxXxrBXfvmtwDj4Ia_U4RmG/view?usp=sharing).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import read_csv
import pandas as pd
import csv
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
import statistics

csv = 'Data.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None, names=['time', 'tide', 'ho', 'tp', 'lo', 'mwd'])
xp = [datetime.strptime(d, "%d/%m/%YT%H:%M") for d in df['time']]

xs = mdates.date2num(xp)
date = mdates.DateFormatter ("%d/%m/%Y\n")

fig = plt.figure(tight_layout=False)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 2)

#Subplot 1 
ax11 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax11.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date)
ax11.set_xlim(dt.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 0), dt.datetime(2019, 9, 30, 0))

ax12 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax12.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date)
ax12.set_xlim(dt.datetime(2020, 8, 1, 0), dt.datetime(2020, 9, 30, 0))

#surveys
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,3,26,14), color = 'red', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,4,10,14), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,4,11,15), color = 'red', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,5,1,9), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,5,3,10), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,5,10,15), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,5,17,9), color = 'red', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,5,20,12), color = 'red', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,6,6,13), color = 'red', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,6,14,8), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,6,18,12), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,6,21,14), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,6,24,16), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,6,25,6), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,6,25,17), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,7,2,11), color = 'red', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,7,3,11), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,7,4,12), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,7,16,10), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,7,31,10), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,8,1,11), color = 'red', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,8,28,9), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax11.axvline(dt.datetime(2019,9,13,11), color = 'red', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')

ax12.axvline(dt.datetime(2020,8,30,11), color = 'red', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax12.axvline(dt.datetime(2020,9,15,9), color = 'blue', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')
ax12.axvline(dt.datetime(2020,9,21,11), color = 'red', linestyle='--', linewidth='1')

#subplot 1
plt.setp(ax11.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
ax11.set_ylabel ('$H_o\ [m]$', size = 12)
ax11.grid(True, ls='--')
ax11.plot(xs, df['ho'], linewidth = 1, color = 'k')

plt.setp(ax12.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
ax12.grid(True, ls='--')
ax12.plot(xs, df['ho'], linewidth = 1, color = 'k')

ax11.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax12.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax11.yaxis.tick_left()
ax11.tick_params(labeltop='off')
ax12.tick_params(labelleft = 'off')
ax12.tick_params(left = 'off')
```

Comment: OK, this is your problem, your LENGTHY problem, but to help you I need a minimum example.  What you thrown at me is simply too much…

Comment: Please provide the _shortest_ code to reproduce the problem

Comment: It looks like you want to use something like: `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2,gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [0.8, 0.2]})`

Comment: I notice that the left subplots have tickmarks every day, and the right subplots have tickmarks every week. If we make the left subplots occupy 80% of the width and the right subplots occupy 20% of the width, how can they be at the same scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task was twofold: first, you wanted the horizontal ratio of the subplot to be 8 to 2. Second, you made the assumption that you wanted to set up a broken axis. The horizontal ratio of the subplot can be handled by `gridspec_ratios=[4,1]` as shown in the comments; the second is to apply the broken axes from the [Broken Axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html). Vertical lines have been omitted.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime

csv = './data/Data_20220114.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None, names=['time', 'tide', 'ho', 'tp', 'lo', 'mwd'])
xp = [datetime.strptime(d, "%d/%m/%YT%H:%M") for d in df['time']]
xs = mdates.date2num(xp)
    months_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y\n')

fig, (ax11, ax12) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12,3), gridspec_kw=dict(width_ratios=[4,1]), sharex=False)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05)

ax11.plot(xs, df['ho'], linewidth = 1, color = 'k')
ax11.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=3))
ax11.xaxis.set_major_formatter(months_fmt)
plt.setp(ax11.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')
ax11.set_ylabel ('$H_o\ [m]$', size = 12)
ax11.grid(True, ls='--')

ax12.plot(xs[-1440:], df['ho'][-1440:], linewidth = 1, color = 'k')
ax12.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax12.xaxis.set_major_formatter(months_fmt)
plt.setp(ax12.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')
ax12.grid(True, ls='--')

ax11.spines.right.set_visible(False)
ax12.spines.left.set_visible(False)
ax11.yaxis.tick_left()
ax12.tick_params(labelleft=False)
ax12.yaxis.tick_right()

d = 0.8  # proportion of vertical to horizontal extent of the slanted line
kwargs = dict(marker=[(-1, -d), (1, d)], markersize=12,
              linestyle="none", color='k', mec='k', mew=1, clip_on=False)
ax11.plot([1, 1], [1, 0], transform=ax11.transAxes, **kwargs)
ax12.plot([0, 0], [1, 0], transform=ax12.transAxes, **kwargs)

plt.show()
```

[image]